# Program producing a bus error when reading in using scanf - C Program

Tags: c, error-handling, scanf

I'm writing a program for an employee database and I'm writing the function to add an employee. I'm getting a bus error after my final prompt to scan in info. I'm pretty sure its to do with my scanf statement as I have a print statement right after that is not printing. Why would I be getting this error?

The prompt in question is for reading in job title.

```
void addEmployee(void)
{
    char *name;
    char gender;
    int age;
    char *title;

    printf("Enter name: \n");   
    scanf(" %100s", name); 
    scanf("%*[^\n]%*c");

    printf("Enter gender: \n");
    scanf(" %1c", &gender); 
    scanf("%*[^\n]%*c");

    printf("Enter age: \n");
    scanf(" %d", &age); 
    scanf("%*[^\n]%*c");

    printf("Enter job title: \n");
    scanf(" %100s", title); 
    scanf("%*[^\n]%*c");

    printf("Test");
    
    printf("The employee you've entered is: %s %c %d %s \n", name, gender, age, title);

    Employee newEmp = {*name, gender, age, *title};
    
    if(employeeList[0] == NULL)
    {
        employeeList[0] =  &newEmp;
        nodeCount++;
    }
}
```

Comment: How much memory do `name` and `title` point to?  What will happen when `scanf` tries to read into the memory pointed to by those pointers?

Comment: You have to allocate storage for strings. You have pointers to nothing/garbage

Comment: name s not even allocated , you need to malloc/calloc it before using in scanf

Comment: Not your problem, but: (1) You do not need the leading space in `" %100s"` and `" %d"`. (2) Given that you are (correctly) using the extra space in `" %1c"`, you do not need those `scanf("%*[^\n]%*c");` lines; they're just confusing extra noise.

Comment: Note: `scanf("%*[^\n]%*c");` does nothing useful when the next character in `stdin` is `'\n'`. The `'\n'` remains in `stdin`.

Answer (score 0):

Code is passing in an *uninitialized* pointer.

```
char *name;  // Pointer 'name' not initialize yet.
printf("Enter name: \n");   
// 'name' passed to scanf() is garbage.  
scanf(" %100s", name);
```

Instead, pass a pointer to an existing array

```
char name[100 + 1];
printf("Enter name: \n");   
// Here the array 'name' coverts to the address of the first element of the array.
// scanf receives a valid pointer.
scanf("%100s", name);
```